# Objective-C UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, bluetooth, uialertaction

I'm trying to add an action to UIAlertAction which can open Bluetooth-settings directly.

Currently I can open the settings, but can anyone help me to change the action from "opening settings" to "opening bluetooth settings"?

```
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                        NSLog(@"Geverifieerd");
                                        NSURL *appSettings = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
                                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appSettings];
                                }];
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not related to UIAlertAction, it's just that you don't know the URL of Bluetooth settings. Since a version of iOS, you can't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page from the Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) there isn't much else you can do, you'll have to trust the user to navigate to the bluetooth settings.